# Letter and number keys don't work in 2.79b

Tags: shortcut

None of the letter or number keys do anything. I can still use the space bar to bring up the search box, but I can't type in anything accept spaces and punctuation symbols. This is only a problem in a few specific .blend files, it works normally in most of them or if I make a new one.
My best guess is I accidentally pressed a button that turns off shortcuts, but I have no idea what button that would be and I can't find anyone else with this problem.

I tried making a copy of the model but the problem is in the copy too.

This has only happened to models I store in Unity project folders.
When I take them out of Unity the problem is still there.

Comment: you could compare your preferences -> input settings between your working and non-working blend files [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PXCw.png

Comment: Thank you for answering. I went to go try this but it started working again before I even did anything.